# Consuming a WCF service by a WPF client

Tags: wcf, consuming

I have created a wcf service and trying to consume by a wpf client. I am unable to see data in datagrid of my wpf client..Here is the code of both wcp & wpf

I have attached all the details in the following url..pls check it out n help me..
http://pastebin.com/8cVKrqci

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 basic possibilities here:

- You are not calling the WCF service
- You are calling the WCF service but it is not returning any data
- You are not binding the data to your datagrid
- The datagrid is not refreshing after the data has been bound

You need to put some logging in your code to identify the problem.

**Edit**

Based on the comments, your problem is that the service is not running on the address that you are using.

Comment: What happens when you call the url http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Jobs/MyJobs/ in internet explorer?

Comment: Nothing happened to this url in internet explorer

Comment: Configure your solution so that the service starts